# Работа с Epub при помощи EpubSharp C#

Tags: c#, epub

Использую бибиблиотеку [EpubSharp](https://github.com/Asido/EpubSharp) для того, чтобы сохранить имеющийся текст в формате .epub. Либо я неправильно понимаю, как работает библиотека, либо что-то делаю не так, потому что при попытке добавить главу сама глава добавляется, а ее заголовок - нет.

```
EpubWriter writer = new EpubWriter();
writer.AddChapter(titleChapter, textChapter);
writer.Write(@"D:\" + textBox3.Text +".epub");
```

`titleChapter` не пустой, проверял. Пока делаю без картинки, автора и всего прочего, что присуще файлу этого расширения. Подскажите, в чем проблема? Ну или предложите альтернативу)

Comment: Автор сам признает, что `Editing capabilities are currently very limited and might not work at all. Use it at your own risk. The next release will bring a true write support.`, т.е. режим записи в настоящий момент крайне ограничен, вполне возможно не все работает как надо. Следующий релиз должен принести настоящую функциональность по записи.

Comment: @Bulson подскажите, а есть какие-нибудь альтернативы, позволяющие сохранять файлы в epub?

Comment: Извините, не знаю.